Image Pyramid for template matching - how will it work with target of arbitrary scale
Consider the classical computer vision problem of template matching. To detect targets of arbitrary size, one approach would be to build an Image Pyramid of the input template: lowpass filter the input image and then subsample it by a factor of 2, and to repeat the process to get the different levels of the pyramid.
So suppose the template is of size 200x200. The different levels (or octave) in the pyramid would have a size of 100x100, 50x50,25x25. My question is this: how will this work if the target of concern has been subsampled/scaled by an arbitrary factor, not a power of 2? Say it has a size of 40x40, matching none of the levels in the pyramid.
Edit: Is this "in-between level" issue a concern for feature detection algorithm such as SURF?
